How to prevent creating new text nodes after 'Enter' press in contenteditable element?
Is it possible using some CSS properties
or HTML attributes or JS solution
prevent splitting text node?
I don't want to call div.normalize() after each 'Enter' press
And please don't suggest using textarea

I need to get a caret position relative to the start of text, but when I press Enter, browser creates each time a new text node and after that the Selection.anchorOffset returns the offset in the new created node. But I want to have the ( ONLY ONE TEXT NODE ) and easy get the caret position


<!DOCTYPE html>Caret:<a id=Caret>0</a> Nodes:<a id=Nodes>1</a>
<div id=div contenteditable='plaintext-only'>Prevent Creating new textNodes</div>
<style>
  #Caret { color: red  }
  #Nodes { color: blue }
  div {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 5lh;
    outline: 1px solid;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overscroll-behavior: contain
  }
</style>
<script>  'use strict';
const sel=getSelection();

div.onkeyup=div.onpointerup=()=>{
  Caret.text=sel.anchorOffset
  Nodes.text=div.childNodes.length
}

</script>



Also I don't want to manually process 'Enter' press
in keydown event via event.preventDefault()
I am search a simple solution
UPDATE:
I am going to highlight via CSS Custom Highlight API CSS Highlight. One div, one textNode ( -> easy get caret and create highlight ranges ). Wrapping to SPAN or something is not needed already. Just One textnode and ranges to highlight
-> My Question: PREVENT CREATING NEW TEXTNODES with ENTER to have ONLY ONE TEXTNODE
Thank You!

Could you explain exactly why you need to do this, what is the actual requirement, because I am not understanding how you are wanting white space treated.

I need to get a caret position relative to the start of text, but when I press Enter, browser creates each time a new text node and after that the Selection.startOffset returns the offset in the new created node. But I want to have the ONLY ONE TEXT NODE and easy get the caret position

I think it would be helpful if you could put your requirement about caret position into the question, rather than saying you must have one text node which may or may not be the solution.

How about if all "enter" keys are ignored?

@Teamur I added an answer using the preventDefault when Enter key gets hit. I know you said you didn't want to ride that strategy.. but I still wonder why. I had to ask before posting.. but it's too late.. please let me know if there's something I got it wrong

If I prevent 'Enter', then maybe via .insertData paste '\n' always to the first Text node.

Instead of preventing the insertion of new nodes (which will prevent you from using rich text, and thus correspond to what a textarea provides), why don't you get a flat offset instead? (very rough PoC https://jsfiddle.net/7r6y5zgs/)

@Kaaiido, thanks, but I wish to avoid any loops

What? Why? That's a very surprising constraint. And note that your contenteditable eleement with just one node is now just a textarea, so even that constraint of not using a textarea makes little sense.

@Kaiido, with textarea I can't highlight text code. Create overlay elements - not for me

Yes you can, textarea also has (its own) selection API.

@Kaiido, I can highlight text range by offset and length with green color in TEXTAREA?

Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/9an3cfm8/

@Kaiido, , I need highlight ranges of code tokens like in code editor, not text selection

Then you need elements inside your contenteditable. And elements are... node.

Is the only editing that you want related to straightforward text - e.g. to add or delete characters anywhere and to color them/highlight them anywhere?

@A Haworth, I am going to highlight via CSS Custom Highlight API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Custom_Highlight_API. One div, one textNode ( -> easy get caret and create highlight ranges ). Wrapping to  or something is not needed already. Just One textnode and ranges to highlight

And why no loops then?

@Kaiido, I will use loops if they have better performance than other solutions

This solution may not be perfectly match with your very narrow requirements where you stated please don't suggest using textarea and Also I don't want to manually process 'Enter' press in keydown event via event.preventDefault().
But you also said: I am search a simple solution and I can't see any easier solution than this...
Using a pre element insteads of div so that the newline will be treated as is and intercepting the Enter key hit preventing the browser's default behaviour that would add a new child text node instead of appending the new content to the unique node.
This solution will just show a content editable element with a fixed height given by its style. If you type new content in there you won't see the node count increase even when you add new lines.


'use strict';

//here I'm fetching the elements explicitely instead of using window scope
const div = document.getElementById('div');
const Caret = document.getElementById('Caret');
const Nodes = document.getElementById('Nodes');

div.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {

    //prevent the default behaviour (where the browser would add a new text node)
    event.preventDefault();

    //determine current caret position and current target content
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const caretPos = selection.anchorOffset;
    const textContent = div.textContent;

    //check if caret is at the end of the content..
    //this is needed because at the end of the content it requires a special behaviour for newline to show up and this condition will be checked when adding the \n
    const atEnd = caretPos === textContent.length;

    //replace the content adding a new line at the caret position
    const newTextContent =
      textContent.slice(0, caretPos)
      + '\n' + (atEnd ? '\n' : '') + textContent.slice(caretPos);
    div.textContent = newTextContent;

    //move the caret after the newline
    setCaretPosition(div, caretPos + 1);

    updateInfo();
  }
});

//move the caret at the new position
function setCaretPosition(elem, pos) {
  const textNode = elem.firstChild;
  const range = document.createRange();
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(textNode, pos);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

function updateInfo() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    Caret.textContent = selection.anchorOffset;
    Nodes.textContent = div.childNodes.length;
  }, 0);
}

div.addEventListener('keyup', updateInfo);
div.addEventListener('click', updateInfo);
div.addEventListener('input', updateInfo);

div.focus();
#Caret {
  color: red
}

#Nodes {
  color: blue
}

#div {
  padding: 10px;
   height: 5lh;
  outline: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;  
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
Caret:<a id="Caret">0</a> Nodes:<a id="Nodes">1</a>
<pre id="div" contenteditable="true">Prevent Creating new textNodes</pre>



